# 500 Internal Server error when logging in to Raspberry Pi Store

Tags: pi-store

I created an account with the Raspberry Pi Store, but each time I attempt to login, I see a 500 Internal Server Error page.

I sent an email to IndieCity and did not receive a response.

I also attempted to reset my password to see if that would work, and did not receive an email.

I can't post on the Raspberry Pi Store forum, since I need an account to do that.

Anyone else having similar issues?

Comment: a 500 response code implies that the problem is on their server not anything that is under your control.

Comment: Is the store down for everyone, then?

Comment: @SteveRobillard It's dead altogether.

Comment: @PandaLion98 I was surprised anyone still used it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought the Raspberry Pi Store died 2 years ago.  Didn't indiecity go bankrupt?

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=83&t=130379

That was a very poor response from Raspberry Pi Org (the foundation).  The store had been defunct for several years. Avoid.

Answer (score 2):

Steve is correct. A [response code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) of 500 means that there's something wrong with the store's web-server. Usually, this means that they have a fatal bug, or some internal system is down.  There's nothing you can do about it.