# Not able to install Pi Store

Tags: pi-store

I tried  to install Pi Store using the following command

> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install pistore

But it does not locate the package pistore. I installed using NOOB package. Please help me know how to install pistore on my Raspberry Pi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pi store died several years ago.

See the related question at [500 Internal Server error when logging in to Raspberry Pi Store](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40787/500-internal-server-error-when-logging-in-to-raspberry-pi-store/40790#40790)